# Style SharePoint web part content to appear on same line

Tags: sharepoint

How do I style a list/announcement web part (currently set to Newsletter style) so that the **Created By** and **Created Date** fields appear on the same line?

[image]

I don't have access to our company's Sharepoint files or Sharepoint designer so was hoping to achieve this through something like the content editor web part or similar.

Comment: You can probably do this with some JavaScript/jQuery in a Script Editor Web Part or via a Content Editor Web Part. Are you familiar with jQuery? Do you already know how to run JavaScript on a SharePoint page?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with? 2010? 2013? 2016?